# BackgroundWorker with SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I know I'm having a massive derp moment here and this is probably quite easy to actually do - I have had a search around and read a few articles but i'm still struggling a little, so any feedback or pointers to useful resources would be greatly appreciated!

Anyway I have a class called `PopulateDatagridViews` which I have various functions in, one of which is called `ExecuteSqlStatement`, this function is simple enough, it initializes an SQL connection and returns a `DataTable` populated with the results of the SQL query. Within the same class I also have various functions that use string builders to build up SQL statements. (Not ideal, I know.)

I create a `PopulateDatagridViews` object in my GUI thread and use it to set various datagrid views with with the returned `DataTables`. For example:

```
dataGridViewVar.DataSource = populateDgv.GetCustomers();
```

Naturally a problem I'm having is that the more data to be read from the database, the longer the U.I is unresponsive. I would like to shift the process of retrieving data via the `PopulateDatagridViews` to a separate thread or `BackgroundWorker` so as prevent the main GUI thread from locking up whilst this is processed.

I realise I can create a `BackgroundWorker` to do this and place in the `DoWork` handler a call to the appropriate function within my `PopulateDatagridViews`.

I figure I could create a `BackgroundWorker` for each individual function inside my `PopulateDatagridViews` class, but surely there is a more efficient way to do this? I'd very much appreciate a point in the right direction on this as it's driving me around the bend!

Additional Info: I use version 4.0 of the .Net framework.

Comment: Which .Net version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.0 of .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you use TPL (Task Parallel Library) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx 
In your case you will create first task to pull some data and than start second task after first is completed to update UI.
I`ll try to find code that i write for similar problem.

Edit: Adding code

```
Task<return_type> t1 = new Task<return_type>(() =>
            {
                //do something to take some result
                return some_result; //return it
            });
            t1.Start();
            Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith((some_arg_that_represent_previous_task_obj) =>{//ContinueWith guarantees that t2 is started AFTER t1 is executed!                

                //Update your GUI here
                //if you need result from previos task:   some_arg_that_represent_previous_task_obj.Result   //Your dataset or whatever

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());  //VERY important - you must update gui from same thread that created it! (you will have cross thread exeption if you dont add TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does indeed sound like what I'd need. I'd very much appreciate a code example if you have one! I really dislike the MSDN examples, they tend to be overly complicated for explaining, well anything really. Heh.

Answer (score 1):

Well in that case I recommend reading this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get some ideas. Afterwards you should look for some tutorials, because the msdn is not the best source to learn things. ;o)

Comment: Haha, yeah I agree on that, I try to use dotnetperls when possible, sadly it isn't as comprehensive as I'd like! great resource though.